# How to pass current date in constant(json text) in aws eventbridge while calling lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, schedule, aws-event-bridge

I have created a event bridge rule which is scheduled to trigger lambda with the following json input. but in the date value I want to pass the current date(sys date) dynamically everytime the schedule is triggered.

{"date": "2019-08-12"}

[image]

Comment: I'd expect the date/time to be present in the [event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-events.html) itself, without you having to provide it.

Comment: can u pls explain in detail, like what option to select and where to pick the date in the event?

Comment: and it is a scheduled event

Answer (score 0):

If you leave the value as the default instead of setting it to constant you'll receive a JSON event which includes the date and time. You can see an example of the format in the [Lambda developer guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-cloudwatchevents.html).

Answer (score 0):

To quote from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-events.html:

> The following fields appear in an event:
> ...
>
> **time**
>
> The event timestamp, which can be specified by the service originating the event. If the event spans a time interval, the service can report the start time, so this value might be before the time the event is received.